# How to retrieve a key value based on another key value form an array object of the response body in karate

Tags: json, foreach, karate

I am new to karate and need your help for the below requirement in karate DSL.

Below is the response (Json array object) I get when I execute a GET request:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
      "id": "11ab",
      "name": "Form1"
    },
    {
      "id": "12bc",
      "name": "Form2"
    }, 
  ]
}
```

Now I need to retrieve value of "id" when I pass value for the key "name" e.g. "Form2".

I tried traversing the Json array object "data" by mapping the "name" key value to get the "id", but unable to get the expected value.

Kindly guide me to achieve this.

Thank you.
Regards,
Ishwar

Comment: see the linked answer. please take some time to read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters

Comment: Thanks a lot!!....I checked the link you referred and able to resolve my issue.